# PHP login won't redirect to the member page

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP problem. I have done a simple login system, but if I login it won't redirect to the members page, it just goes to a blank page. The login works, as I tried just `echo("success")`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("mysite","hidden","hidden") or die("Couldn't   connect");
    mysql_select_db("hidden") or die("Couldn't find db");   

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        //code to login
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            //validate values
            $dbusername = $row['Username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
        }
        //check to see if the values match
        if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
        {
            header('Location: memberHome.php');
            $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
        }
        else
            die("incorrect password");
    }
    else
        die("User doesn't exist");
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");
?>
```

Comment: do you still have `echo("success");` in your original code?  You cannot echo/print anything on the page before sending custom headers. Get rid of any possible echo's that occur before that header statement.

Comment: And you're also open to SQL injection attacks. Look into using prepared statements or if you're lazy: `mysql_real_escape_string();`.

Comment: Someone should probably ask you if memberHome.php is in the same directory/context path as the login.php page. There's no forward slash before memberHome.php. Not sure if that is needed or not...

Comment: @navnav I have deleted the echo("success");. I don't think that's the problem though. Also, i know about the sql injection attack, I'm just trying to do the basics first and then fix the rest. Thanks for the suggestion! ;)

Comment: @jmort253 Yes, memberHome.php is in the same directory. And i tried with the forward slash as well but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: Hey, there was a user that pointed out there is a space before ` <?php`. Is that just a typo or is it like that in your code? Did you check to make sure there are no spaces before your PHP tag? Spaces are counted as "output", which could affect your headers.

Comment: @jmort253 I have no spaces before the '<?php' I just had to tab it out for stackoverflow's output. Thanks for that tip though, I wasn't aware of that. There must be something small like that in my code that's messing the header.

Comment: Guys, I found my mistake. It was of course something very silly. The problem was that I had html tags around the php code. I tried taking them out before and the code still didn't work but when I did that i left a space before the '<?php'. So now I took out both the space and the html tags. I appreciate all of your help and I apologize for making such a silly mistake. :)

Comment: User @Andy who had the downvoted answer should come back and undelete it. He was right after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: memberHome.php');
$_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
```

if you want the session variable to be assigned you'll have to do so before the header passes you through to the next page ;) like this:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
header('Location: memberHome.php');
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this as well but it still doesn't work. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: well, then are you sure the file you wish to refer to is actually called memberHome.php (case-sensitive)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for everything. Found my mistake though, I had html tags around the php code. Silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried die after the header?

```
$_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
header('Location: memberHome.php');
die;
```

Comment: Hey. I just tried with die; and it doesn't seem to work. I bet it's something very silly in my code but i just can't get around it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Np. What happens if you echo $dbusername right before the condition. And also, have you checked if there's any encryption (like md5) included in the password field? in that case 
$dbpassword = md5($row['Password'])

Comment: It echoes back my username. Also, i had MD5's for the password but I took them out because I had problems, I'll put them back in though once I get this sorted.

Comment: It doesn't seem to redirect. the blank page still has the following http  http://www.mywebsite.com/project/login.php

Comment: I'd 
echo $dbpassword .' ('.strlen($dbpassword).') -  '.$password.' ('.strlen($password).').'<br />'; 
before condition to match input with db in human eyes.

Comment: Hey. I appreciate your help. i had found the mistake though. html tags around the php code. I knew it was something stupid like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than first checking to see if the username exists and then looking if the password is correct, why not do both at the same time?

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE Username='$username' 
    AND pass='$password'"));

if($row['id']) { 
$_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
header('Location: memberHome.php');
}
```

Also, it's wise not to use `*` in your `SELECT` statement. Only select the items you actually need.

I don't see any problems with your code in respect to it not redirecting.

I just tried it locally on my machine with this code and taking out your DB connections. But using the code supplied below, I was able to get it to redirect to memberHome.php, which shows that if the username and password are matching, then it is working correct.

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = "david";
$password = "password";

if($username&&$password)
{
    //$connect = mysql_connect("mysite","hidden","hidden") or die("Couldn't   connect");
   //mysql_select_db("hidden") or die("Couldn't find db");   

    //$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");
    $numrows = 1;

    if($numrows!=0)
    {

            //validate values
            $dbusername = "david";
            $dbpassword = "password";

        //check to see if the values match
        if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
        {
            header('Location: memberHome.php');
            $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
        }
        else
            die("incorrect password");
    }
    else
        die("User doesn't exist");
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi Jako, great suggestion, but I don't think this addresses the question. boolchick made it clear that she is able to see the echo("success"), meaning her auth strategy works, it's just the header Location that doesn't appear to be working correctly. On SO, answers, in general, should answer the question. Consider editing this to improve it, or remove it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. I'll see if I can tweak my answer to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi Jako. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it and get back to you soon.

Comment: Hey. Found my mistake. had html tags around the php code. Thanks for all the help though!